# Call a method in Select() of an Entity Framework Core method expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 API endpoints which have similarities so I am trying to reuse some similar code. I have an EF Core method syntax to retrieve data and this query is used in both.

Rather than repeat it in both, as the `Select()`s are identical, I am trying to put it into a method.

This is one of the queries

```
var exhibitors = await Db.CompanyDescriptions
    .Join(Db.Companies, cd => cd.CompanyId, c => c.CompanyID, (cd, c) => new { cd, c })
    .Where(q => uniques.Any(id => id == q.cd.CompanyId)).Where(q => q.cd.EventId == eventId)
    .Select(s => new ExhibitorModel()
    {
        Id = s.cd.Id,
        EventId = s.cd.EventId,
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Snipped for brevity, but I have this same code in another method (mostly) and then the methods go separate ways in terms of the unit of work, so I am trying to do something like this:

```
private ExhibitorModel MarshallExhibitorModel(CompanyDescriptions cd, Company c)
{
    return new ExhibitorModel()
    {
        Id = cd.Id,
        EventId = cd.EventId,
    };
}
```

And then be able to use that in both `Select()`s, but I am unsure of how to form that syntax.

In this line

```
.Select(s => new ExhibitorModel()
```

How can I say call MarshallExhibitorModel and pass in `s.companydescription` and `s.company` ?

Comment: The method needs to be called client side (as it can't be converted to SQL). For an example of doing this, see [Using Function in Select Clause of Entity Framework Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6430213/1364358)

Comment: Is there a good reason why you aren't using a navigation property between Company & CompanyDescriptions? Having an anonymous type in the query complicates the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have to do expression expanding. It means that you have to preprocess Expression Tree before feeding LINQ Provider with the query. Easiest way to do that is using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Create function which returns Lambda Expression with the same parameters types:

```
public static Expression<Func<CompanyDescriptions, Company, ExhibitorModel>> MarshallExhibitorModel()
{
    return (cd, c) => ExhibitorModel()
    {
        Id = cd.Id,
        EventId = cd.EventId,
    };
}
```

And then use this function in your query. Don't forget to call `AsExpandable()` at least once in the query.

```
var exhibitors = await Db.CompanyDescriptions
    .Join(Db.Companies, cd => cd.CompanyId, c => c.CompanyID, (cd, c) => new { cd, c })
    .Where(q => uniques.Any(id => id == q.cd.CompanyId)).Where(q => q.cd.EventId == eventId)
    .AsExpandable() // important
    .Select(s => MarshallExhibitorModel().Invoke(s.cd, s.c))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Even better you can use such function in different situations:

```
    ...
    .AsExpandable() // important
    .Select(s => new SomeDTO 
       { 
          Exhibitor = MarshallExhibitorModel().Invoke(s.cd, s.c))
       }
    .ToListAsync();
```

This approach also can be used for generating complex reusable predicates which depend on parameters.

Answer (score 1):

First, including the anonymous type `(cd, c) => new { cd, c }` would make code-reuse almost impossible. It looks like you only reference cd.Id, cd.CompanyId and cd.EventId. You could define an explicit type with these fields. Since you're only referring to `CompanyDescriptions`, it doesn't look like you need the join at all in this case. But even if you did, I am wondering why you aren't using navigation properties.

Ignoring that, you are then calling `IQueryable<>.Select()`, which takes an argument of type `Expression<Func<,>>`. This forces the C# compiler to construct an expression tree instead of compiling your lambda directly to a `Func<,>`.

You can define both an `Expression<Func<,>>` and a `Func<,>` from the same source;

```cs
    public static Expression<Func<CompanyDescriptions,ExhibitorModel>> expression = 
        cd => new ExhibitorModel()
        {
            Id = cd.Id,
            EventId = cd.EventId,
        };
    public static Func<CompanyDescriptions,ExhibitorModel> func = expression.Compile();
```

Just make sure you use the right one for `IQueryable<>.Select(expression)` vs `IEnumerable<>.Select(func)`.

Answer (score -1):

Just call function inside select. Add static in MarshallExhibitorModel() function too.

```
.Select(s => MarshallExhibitorModel(s.cd, s.c)
```

Comment: Don't do that at home or even at work. Instead of selecting two ids, two full entities will be transferred to the client. Better to delete this answer.